# Vuelidate not working as expected with dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuelidate

I'm using the [Vuelidate](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate) package for form validation in my Vue app. This is working great for all basic forms but I have one form that generates dynamic form inputs based on what is returned from the server.

Here is my form:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="onSubmit">
      <fieldset>
        <div v-for="input in inputList" :key="input.label">
          <input :type="input.type" v-model="form[input.detail]" :placeholder="input.label">
          <div v-if="submitted && !$v.form[input.detail].required" class="invalid-feedback">{{input.label}} is required</div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <input id="form-submit" type="submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my Form data:

```js
import { required } from "vuelidate/lib/validators";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      inputList: [
        { detail: "player_points", type: "number", label: "Player Points" },
        { detail: "player_rebounds", type: "number", label: "Player Rebounds" }
      ],
      form: {
        player_points: null,
        player_rebounds: null
      },
      submitted: false
    };
  },
  validations() {
    return {
      form: {
        player_points: { required }
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit: function() {
      this.submitted = true;

      this.$v.$touch();
      if (this.$v.$invalid) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

As you can see I'm trying to validate only `player_points` field and NOT the `player_rebounds` field but I'm hitting a issue. This works fine if I try and validate both.

Here is the example code:

[CODE SANDBOX EXAMPLE](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sun-043yj?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

You'll be able to replicate the problem I'm seeing here.

#### Desired outcome.

Just the `Player Points` field has the validation applied to it.